# How do I move Picks from a Collection to a Folder in Lightroom 3?

Tags: software, lightroom, lightroom-3

On one of the rare occasions I've used Lightroom Collections, I found myself wanting to transfer the Pick/Reject info from the Collection back to the main Folder the photos are in.  Picks are Collection-local, and there doesn't seem to be a built-in way of doing it.  The best I could come up with is using a tag or coloured flag (which are global) as a temporary marker, allowing me to edit the Picks in the Folder.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I believe that in Lightroom 4, the flags / picks appear on the image wherever you view them - be it in a collection or in their original folder.  (I.e. they're now global)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporarily tagging them is probably the best move. I've hit this same frustration before and that's how I moved on.

Comment: Agree.  Tags, colors, or stars are the workaround.

Comment: OK, that'll have to do! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this issue is a real bugbear. I actually see it as a defect of the software and it is one of the more compelling reasons to upgrade to Lightroom 4, where flag status is global, rather than local to a Collection.